# Dynamically select and check nested object field Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a Typescript interface with some nested objects

```
export interface Authorisation {
    aliases_read: boolean;
    aliases_write: boolean;
}

export interface User {
    id: string;
    authorisation: Authorisation;
}
```

I would like to access a field dynamically and get its value within my function

```
    function checkPermissions(permFlag : string): boolean {
        return console.log(user?.authorisation[permFlag])
    }
```

If I pass in `aliases_read` to my function I get the error

```
AuthProvider.tsx:50 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'aliases_read')
```

Is there something I need to do differently when accesing nested objects like this?

When I `console.log` my user object I can see the value

```
user: 
 authorisation: 
   aliases_read:true 
   aliases_write:true
```

Comment: try `function checkPermissions(permFlag: keyof Authorisation): boolean`

Comment: I would send the user to checkPermissions function like `function(user, permFlag)`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue is caused because `user` is undefined and in that case, a simple check might solve the issue.

```
    function checkPermissions(permFlag : string): boolean {
        if (!user) return false;
        return console.log(user.authorisation[permFlag])
    }
```

Comment: When I `console.log` the user it looks like its defined which is strange